# Cant' found main class at JAR generated

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

how do you do?

I am doing a project and I have to generate a JAR file. When creating the JAr and trying to execute it, it tells me that the main class is not found or has not been loaded.

[image]

I have been looking for where my error is, but I cannot find it, in my MANIFEST.MF file I have set the Main-Class:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: AudiSyncTool
```

And this is my main class:

```
import make.WindowInterface;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class AudiSyncTool {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()){
        WindowInterface windowInterface = WindowInterface.getInstance();
        windowInterface.runApp();
    }
}
}
```

And my main class it is at default package.

And in my pom.xml file I have the apache plugin set to generate JAR files.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>AudiSyncTool</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any advice or suggestion on how to solve this problem of not being able to generate JAR files correctly?

It goes without saying that when I run the code everything works fine. But not when I generate the JAR.

Thanks.

Comment: Built it as `executable` jar instead of normal jar. And choose the correct main class while creating.

Answer (score 0):

You need run with -jar
java -jar synctoolaudi.jar